# Using react component when returned in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use the following timepicker component in a parent, but it is being provided in a format that I am unfamiliar with:

```
"use strict";

(function (global, factory) {
if (typeof exports === "object" && typeof module !== "undefined") module.exports = factory();
if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) define(factory);
(global || window).AReactTimepicker = factory();
})(this, function () {
var React = typeof require === "function" ? require("react") : window.React;

var CLOCK_SIZE = 222;

var TimePicker = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
        return {
            visible: false,
            hour: 12,
            minute: 0,
            am: true,
            position: {
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }
        };
    },

    componentWillMount: function componentWillMount() {
        document.addEventListener("click", this.hideOnDocumentClick);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener("click", this.hideOnDocumentClick);
    },

    show: function show() {
        var trigger = this.refs.trigger.getDOMNode(),
            rect = trigger.getBoundingClientRect(),
            isTopHalf = rect.top > window.innerHeight / 2;

        this.setState({
            visible: true,
            position: {
                top: isTopHalf ? rect.top + window.scrollY - CLOCK_SIZE - 3 : rect.top + trigger.clientHeight + window.scrollY + 3,
                left: rect.left
            }
        });
    },

    hide: function hide() {
        this.setState({
            visible: false
        });
    },

    hideOnDocumentClick: function hideOnDocumentClick(e) {
        if (!this.parentsHaveClassName(e.target, "time-picker")) this.hide();
    },

    parentsHaveClassName: function parentsHaveClassName(element, className) {
        var parent = element;
        while (parent) {
            if (parent.className && parent.className.indexOf(className) > -1) return true;

            parent = parent.parentNode;
        }

        return false;
    },

    onTimeChanged: function onTimeChanged(hour, minute, am) {
        this.setState({
            hour: hour,
            minute: minute,
            am: am
        });
    },

    onDone: function onDone() {
        this.hide();
    },

    render: function render() {
        return <div className="time-picker">
            <input ref="trigger" type="text" readOnly="true" value={_getTimeString(this.state.hour, this.state.minute, this.state.am)} onClick={this.show} />
            <Clock visible={this.state.visible} position={this.state.position} onTimeChanged={this.onTimeChanged} onDone={this.onDone} hour={this.state.hour} minute={this.state.minute} am={this.state.am} />
        </div>;
    }
});

var Clock = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
        return {
            hoursVisible: true,
            minutesVisible: false,
            position: "below"
        };
    },

    componentWillReceiveProps: function componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
        if (this.props.visible && !props.visible) this.setState({
            hoursVisible: true,
            minutesVisible: false,
            amPmVisible: false
        });
    },

    getTime: function getTime() {
        return {
            hour: this.props.hour,
            minute: this.props.minute,
            am: this.props.am
        };
    },

    onHourChanged: function onHourChanged(hour) {
        this._hour = hour;
        this.setState({
            hoursVisible: false,
            minutesVisible: true
        });
    },

    onHoursHidden: function onHoursHidden() {
        this.props.onTimeChanged(this._hour, this.props.minute, this.props.am);
    },

    onMinuteChanged: function onMinuteChanged(minute) {
        this.props.onDone();
        this._minute = minute;

        this.setState({
            minutesVisible: false,
            amPmVisible: true
        });
    },

    onMinutesHidden: function onMinutesHidden() {
        this.props.onTimeChanged(this.props.hour, this._minute, this.props.am);
    },

    onAmPmChanged: function onAmPmChanged(am) {
        this.props.onTimeChanged(this.props.hour, this.props.minute, am);
    },

    style: function style() {
        return {
            top: this.props.position.top,
            left: this.props.position.left
        };
    },

    render: function render() {
        return <div className={"clock " + (this.props.visible ? "clock-show" : "clock-hide")} style={this.style()}>
            <div className="clock-face-wrapper">
                <Hours visible={this.state.hoursVisible} time={this.getTime()} onClick={this.onHourChanged} onHidden={this.onHoursHidden} />
                <Minutes visible={this.state.minutesVisible} time={this.getTime()} onClick={this.onMinuteChanged} onHidden={this.onMinutesHidden} />
            </div>
            <AmPmInfo time={this.getTime()} onChange={this.onAmPmChanged} />
        </div>;
    }
});

var AmPmInfo = React.createClass({
    render: function render() {
        var time = this.props.time;
        return <div className="am-pm-info">
            <div className={"am" + (time.am ? " selected" : "")} onClick={this.props.onChange.bind(null, true)}>AM</div>
            <div className="time">{_getTimeString(time.hour, time.minute, time.am)}</div>
            <div className={"pm" + (!time.am ? " selected" : "")} onClick={this.props.onChange.bind(null, false)}>PM</div>
        </div>;
    }
});

var Hours = React.createClass({
    buildHours: function buildHours() {
        var hours = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) hours.push(i);
        return hours;
    },

    render: function() {
        var { time, ...props } = this.props;
        return <Face {...props} type="hours" values={this.buildHours()} selected={this.props.time.hour} />;
    }
});

var Minutes = React.createClass({
    buildMinutes: function buildMinutes() {
        var minutes = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) minutes.push(_pad((i === 12 ? 0 : i) * 5));
        return minutes;
    },

    render: function() {
        var { time, ...props } = this.props;
        return <Face {...props} type="minutes" values={this.buildMinutes()} selected={this.props.time.minute} />;
    }
});

var Face = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function componentDidMount() {
        this.refs.face.getDOMNode().addEventListener("transitionend", this.onTransitionEnd);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function componentWillUnmount() {
        this.refs.face.getDOMNode().removeEventListener("transitionend", this.onTransitionEnd);
    },

    onTransitionEnd: function onTransitionEnd(e) {
        if (e.propertyName === "opacity" && e.target.className.indexOf("face-hide") > -1) this.props.onHidden();
    },

    render: function render() {
        return <div ref="face" className={"face " + this.props.type + (this.props.visible ? " face-show" : " face-hide")}>
            {this.props.values.map(function(value, i) {
                return <div key={i} className={"position position-" + (i + 1) + (parseInt(this.props.selected) === parseInt(value) ? " selected" : "")} onClick={this.props.onClick.bind(null, value)}>
                    {_pad(value)}
                </div>
            }.bind(this))}
            <LongHand type={this.props.type} selected={this.props.selected} />
            <div className="inner-face"></div>
            <Ticks />
        </div>;
    }
});

var LongHand = React.createClass({
    render: function render() {
        var deg = (this.props.selected / (this.props.type === "hours" ? 12 : 60) * 360);
        return <div>
            <div className="long-hand" style={{ transform: "rotate(" + deg + "deg) scale(1, 0.8)", WebkitTransform: "rotate(" + deg + "deg) scale(1, 0.8)" }}></div>
            <div className="long-hand-attachment"></div>
        </div>;
    }
});

var Ticks = React.createClass({
    buildTick: function buildTick(index) {
        return React.createElement(
            "div",
            { key: index, className: "tick " + (index % 5 === 0 ? "big " : ""), style: { transform: "rotate(" + index * 6 + "deg)", WebkitTransform: "rotate(" + index * 6 + "deg)" } },
            React.createElement("div", null)
        );
    },

    render: function render() {
        var ticks = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++)
            ticks.push(this.buildTick(i));

        return <div className="ticks">
            {ticks}
        </div>;
    }
});

function _pad(value) {
    value = value.toString();
    return value.length === 1 ? "0" + value : value;
}

function _getTimeString(hour, minute, am) {
    return hour + ":" + _pad(minute) + " " + (am ? "AM" : "PM");
}

return TimePicker;
});
```

It seems to return a class, but I am unsure of how to incorporate it into the parent. I'm used to the typical method like so:

```
import {Child} from 'childlocation';

export class Parent extends React.Component<any, any>{

render: function render() {
    return <div>
         <Child />
    </div>;
}
};
```

But I am not able to get the above code to properly execute in the parent. I have attempted to declare a variable that is equal to the function, but the component is blank when the code is executed. I also tried various combinations of export default and simply exporting the function as a variable and it doesn't seem to work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Just use them like you would with class components!

Comment: Like this: `import TimePicker from 'a-fore-men-tioned-file.js';`